# Trying to understand why my MUI TextField select is blank after making selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, trpc.io

I have a weird issue where sometimes when I try to filter by tags in my T3 application, the select is shown as blank instead of the selected filter.  It still works correctly and shows what it should below, just that the select element is blank.

I get a warning in the console:
MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `clh3puird0003ughkknl9xo9f,clhkd5cli0001ug4w1tbcygc1,clh22iqsg0003ug1kdkfmeqne` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are `clh3puird0003ughkknl9xo9f,clh4p0ntx0001ugb8cri3x7h8`, `clhq7r0tf000lug9oelp8b0jb,clh3g59wd0001ughk293sfpaq,clh3puird0003ughkknl9xo9f,clh25wljp0001mg07zwwaontn`, `clh3g59wd0001ughk293sfpaq`, `clh3puird0003ughkknl9xo9f,clh22iqsg0003ug1kdkfmeqne`, `clh3puird0003ughkknl9xo9f,clh25wljp0001mg07zwwaontn`, `clh4p7at60003ugb88ngny2wm`, `clhepw5az0005ugzo55lh4av0,clh3puird0003ughkknl9xo9f,clh25wljp0001mg07zwwaontn`, `clhkd5cli0001ug4w1tbcygc1,clh3puird0003ughkknl9xo9f,clh22iqsg0003ug1kdkfmeqne`, `clh3g59wd0001ughk293sfpaq,clh3puird0003ughkknl9xo9f`.

This doesn't happen every time I click on a value in the select.

[image: a picture of hte select in question with its options]

and here is how it looks after selecting.
[image]

The data of the tag name and the count present in the data is sent by the backend and saved in state, and then mapped to the TextField element.  A ref of what is selected is then passed down to a component that displays the items based on the ids that were sent in the ref.

Here is where the select is present:

```
const FoodItemsPage = () => {
  const {
    householdId,

  } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [filterItemsCategory, setFilterItemsCategory] = useState("All");
  const [foodTypesList, setFoodTypesList] = useState<FoodType[]>();

  const getFoodTypesRoute = api.useContext().items;
  const getFoodTypes = api.items.getFoodCategoryCount.useQuery({
    householdId,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getFoodTypes.data && setFoodTypesList(getFoodTypes.data);
  }, [getFoodTypes.data]);

  const foodTypeRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);
  
  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setFilterItemsCategory(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="bg-snow">
        <div className="w-full">
          <div className="w-full ">
            <Searchbar />
          </div>
          <div className="">
            {filterItemsCategory === "Food Type" && (
              <div className="mt-2 flex w-full gap-1 px-2">
                <FormControl className="w-full">
                  <InputLabel id="filterItemsBy">Filter By:</InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    labelId="filterItemsBy"
                    id="filterItemsBy"
                    value={filterItemsCategory}
                    label="Filter By"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value="All">All</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Storage Area">Storage Area</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Food Type">Food Type</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Expiring Soon">Expiring Soon</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <TextField
                  select
                  label="Food Type"
                  className="w-full"
                  id="foodType"
                  inputRef={foodTypeRef}
                  onChange={async () => {
                    await getFoodTypesRoute.invalidate();
                    console.log(foodTypeRef);
                  }}
                  defaultValue=""
                >
                  {foodTypesList !== null &&
                    foodTypesList
                      ?.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1))
                      .map((type, i) => (
                        <MenuItem key={i} value={type.ids}>
                          {type.name}({type.count})
                        </MenuItem>
                      ))}
                </TextField>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>

          <div className="mt-2">
            <FoodItems
              sortType={filterItemsCategory}
              storageAreaId={
                storageAreaRef.current && storageAreaRef.current.value
              }
              foodTypeIds={foodTypeRef}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I pulled out a lot of the unnecessary code in the page but if it helps the whole project can be found at https://github.com/sjohnston82/quarter-master2

Edit:  I wanted to add the backend route returning the category counts mapped to the select element in question in case it might help:

```
getFoodCategoryCount: protectedProcedure
    .input(z.object({ householdId: z.string() }))
    .query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const allItems = await ctx.prisma.item.findMany({
        where: { householdId: input.householdId },
      });
      const categoryCounts: { name: string; count: number; ids: string[] }[] =
        [];

      allItems.forEach((item) => {
        item.foodCategories.forEach((category) => {
          const existingCategory = categoryCounts.find(
            (count) => count.name === category
          );
          if (existingCategory) {
            existingCategory.count++;
            existingCategory.ids.push(item.id);
          } else {
            categoryCounts.push({ name: category, count: 1, ids: [item.id] });
          }
        });
      });

      return categoryCounts;
    }),
```

Thank you for your time and knowledge.